# Why do I get a lambda error that no-one else gets?

Tags: moles

I'm trying to debug the following line:

```
MOrigValue.AllInstances.TestString = () => "New value";
```

There's a red squiggly line under:

```
() => "New value";
```

Mouseover shows the following error:

```
Delegate 'Microsoft.Moles.Framework.MolesDelegates.Func<OrigValueP.OrigValue, string>' does not take 0 arguments
```

Here is the complete class:

```
namespace OrigValueP
{
    public class OrigValue
    {
        public string TestString() { return "Original value"; }
    }
}
```

Here's the info from the object browser.

Click on the property MOrigValue.AllInstances.TestString:

```
public static Microsoft.Moles.Framework.MolesDelegates.Func<OrigValueP.OrigValue,string> TestString { set; }
Member of OrigValueP.Moles.MOrigValue.AllInstances
```

So, to a non-techie like me, that would explain the red squiggly line error above..

Click on the property MOrigValue..TestString:

```
public Microsoft.Moles.Framework.MolesDelegates.Func<string> TestString { set; }
Member of OrigValueP.Moles.MOrigValue
```

To me, this looks like the definition that I would have expected to see for MOrigValue.AllInstances.TestString. In other words a property that is actually a Moled "method" that has no parameters and returns a string.

As an experiment, based on the first object browser info above, I inserted the class as an input parameter, as follows:

```
MOrigValue.AllInstances.TestString = (OrigValue) => "New value";
```

This works :)

But my workaround looks like a "hack". I've seen every page on the internet (including StackOverflow) relating to moles and how to remove them painlessly. Many of them have lines with a lambda similar to the following:

```
MMyClass.AllInstances.DoSomething = () => "Hello world";
Assert.AreEqual("Hello world", new MyClass().DoSomething());
```

The fundamental issue is that Moles started from a method that takes no parameters and returns a string. The Moled equivalent takes its own class as a parameter and returns a string. Surely Moles knows that TestString() is a member of OrigValue.

Maybe my problem is a result of using VS Express, rather than the paid versions. I can live with that, but it would still be interesting to know why I need the hack. There might be cases where the hack produces incorrect test results without my knowledge.

BTW: I think this example proves the value of the object browser.

Answer (score 0):

Your expectation is wrong. The "hack" you describe is the official documented way to use the `AllInstances` nested type. Its delegates really do always take a parameter containing an instance of the type under test.

It is unlikely that you could have seen this form of usage of `AllInstances`

```
MMyClass.AllInstances.DoSomething = () => "Hello world";
```

which, if you have, could be a mistake made by the author of the code.

What you expect to be the definition of a delegate belonging to the `AllInstances` type is really a different kind of use of Moles: it's used to detour an instance method of a single instance.

The "Mole Basics" section of the document "Microsoft Moles Reference Manual" contains more information on the topic. Here is an excerpt from there.

### Instance Methods (for One Instance)

... The properties to set up those moles are instance methods of the mole type itself. Each instantiated mole type is also associated with a raw instance of a moled method type.

For example, given a class `MyClass` with an instance method `MyMethod`:

```
public class MyClass {
    public int MyMethod() {
        ...
    }
}
```

We can set up two mole types of `MyMethod` such that the first one always returns 5 and the second always returns 10:

```
var myClass1 = new MMyClass() { MyMethod = () => 5 };
var myClass2 = new MMyClass() { MyMethod = () => 10 };
```